# Windows 10: How can I make my mouse scroll the page on one monitor, while my cursor is active on a different monitor?

Tags: windows-10

I have just switched over to a Windows 10 device from an OSX device.

Imagine I have a web page open full screen on my external monitor, and an excel spreadsheet open full screen on my built-in monitor on my laptop.

With my Apple computer I was able to scroll through the webpage on one monitor using the scroll wheel on my mouse while I had my cursor active on the spreadsheet. This allowed my to read through the web page (as long as my pointer was touching the web page and enter information into the spreadsheet without clicking back and forth between the two. I was able to simultaneously navigate the spreadsheet with the arrows on my keyboard and navigate up and down through the web page with the scroll wheel.

With the Windows system I have to actually click on the web page to scroll through it, then click back on the spreadsheet to enter info into it. This is very inconvenient. Is there a fix for this?

Edit: It seems that this issue only exists when working with two different programs, for example; excel and internet explorer. I can scroll the way I would like between two internet explorer windows, but not when one window is internet explorer and the other is excel.

Comment: It should work that way by default. (I am writing this comment while scrolling other windows just to be sure). If you have, for example, [Synaptics touchpad driver (touchpad icon in system tray)](https://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD3101Z30000R01.htm) it can override this behavior to scrolling active window instead of under-pointer window - you can easily change it in settings.

Comment: I followed your link to the Synaptics page and followed the instructions to the settings, however I don't find anything in my settings regarding this particular feature. Any advice on how to locate the particular setting that needs changed? I did change to a new keyboard when I got this computer so it is possible the issue lies within the keyboard program but when I try the same operation with my built in touchpad I get the same negative result.

Comment: This seems to be an issue others have experienced although it seems to pertain strictly to excel in the more recent updates to windows 10. No resolution in sight. The problem is unique to excel and doesn't happen in word or other programs. Here is a link to the Microsoft answers page where the issue is being discussed. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/excel-scrolls-the-wrong-window-on-hover/0cfd5f7f-865d-44d6-a985-7edd77d6c5e6